# How to search in a txt file. Show the line that contains the specified expression and the line after that?

Tags: python, search, full-text-search

I have a .txt file which has lines that look like:

```
175- HAMURABI WAS THE CREATOR OF WHAT EMPIRE?
R: BABYLONIC
176- WAR OF 30 YEARS OCCURRED IN WHAT PERIOD?
R: 1618-1648
177- WHO IS THE VILLAIN OF THE CARTOON "THE SMURFS"?
R: GARGAMEL
178- TRUE NAME OF ERIC ARTHUR BLAIR?
R: GEORGE ORWELL
179- IN WHICH AFRICAN COUNTRY IS MOUNT KILIMANJARO LOCATED, WITH 5895 ALTITUDE METERS?
R: T ANZANIA
```

I want the code to show (for example) the line with `war of 30 years occurred in what period?`. It should do a case-insensitive search.

What I really want is a result like:

```
**176- WAR OF 30 YEARS OCCURRED IN WHAT PERIOD?
R: 1618-1648**
```

I know how to open a file and read the lines, but I'm stuck after that. How can I search the file?

Comment: Just a for loop and if condition will do

Comment: "I wanna my code show me (for example) the line with `**war of 30 years occurred in what period?**`" Well, *how do you know* that is the line you want the code to show, and not any other line? You can only do a search if you have a rule that tells you when you have found what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service. Please give it a try and come back to edit your question with the code you actually tried.
We will be glad to answer to more precise technical question based on your code.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that is working for me:

```
a = "search"
lines = 0
resuls = []
resp = []
with open ("pr.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for l in file:
        lines += 1

        resp.append(l.rstrip())

        if a.lower() in l.lower():
            result.append((lines, l.rstrip()))

for i in resul:
    print(i[1])
    print(resp[i[0]])
```

**thanks so much for all the help**

Answer (score 1):

You could open the file and read all lines:

```
file = open("Path",mode="rt")
LineList = file.readlines()
```

LineList is now a List with one String value per Line.
You can access every line with its index (starting at 0 => Line 1 = Index 0)

You can search the List with an for loop and compare each String against Searchkey.

```
searchKey = '176- WAR OF 30 YEARS OCCURRED IN WHAT PERIOD?'

def findIndex(searchKey):
    index = -1
    for line in LineList:
        index = index + 1
        linePosition = line.find(searchKey)
        if linePosition != -1:
            break
    return index
```

The Answer would be just the matching line's index + 1

```
print(LineList[findIndex(Searchkey)])
print(LineList[findIndex(Searchkey) + 1])
```

Searchkey would be the String you are searching for

Comment: Pls give a example

Comment: Here you go.
You could also read any character from line between question and answer.
Sou you would reveal the answer just after the input of any key.

Comment: So: `import os, time

a = open('pr.txt', 'rt', encoding="utf-8")
lis = a.readlines()

def findIndex(Searchkey):
    index = -1
    for line in lis:
        index = index + 1
        linePosition = line.find(Searchkey)
        if linePosition != -1:
            break
    return index

print(lis[findIndex(Searchkey)])
print(lis[findIndex(Searchkey) + 1])` Where exactly I'll put my search-key? I've been trying everywhere you mention **Searchkey** n it's print the error `NameError: name 'Searchkey' is not defined
`

Comment: Searchkey is just a name for the String you are searching. You could name this variable however you want. 
You could also replace Searchkey directly with the String you are searching.
I will update this in the example!

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("a.txt")
data = file.readlines();
file.close()
search_data = {data[i]:data[i+1] for i in range(len(data)-1)}
```

This should give your answer based on your question. If you want to match the pattern on the dictionary key you can try to match and then get from dictionary

Comment: In that solution I can't see where exactly I'll put my search-key

Answer (score 0):

**This code solved part of the problem:**

```
ques = []
substr = "my SearchedKey".lower()
with open ('pr.txt', 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line.lower().find(substr) != -1:
            ques.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for answ in ques:
    print(answ)
```

From there, How to print the line that comes after?